# Версия HTTP запроса

Tags: c#, httpclient

Почему в запросе всё таки Version: 1.1, если использую `httpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0);`

```
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.Brotli,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true
        };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0);
```

В запросе:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, "https://***.php");
```

Вот такие данные:

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: nginx/1.18.0
  Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2021 11:14:44 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.8
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://***.ru
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
}}
```

Comment: Вохможно сервер не поддерживает HTTP/2, надо смотреть в трафик.

Comment: Может сервер не поддерживает 2.0? Мало ли что ваш клиент хочет 2.0 - но данный сервер nginx  настроен так, что работает только по 1.0 и 1.1

Comment: @aepot @A K - вот как раз странности происходят) что то в DevTools Google Chtome версию вроде как не показывает. Но вот FireFox при пост запросе в одно и тоже место показывает рандомно, то 2.0, то 1.1

Comment: Непонятно, да. Надо прозванивать всю цепочку, смотреть чтобы не было подмен, прокси/антивирусов по пути - мало ли что может случиться.

Comment: @AK этот же адрес показывает в Google Chrome DevTools что у меня присутствуют псевдо-заголовки 2.0 ":authority" и т.д.

Comment: у меня `using var response = await new HttpClient() { DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0) }.GetAsync("https://aepot.ru"); Console.WriteLine(response);` возвращает `StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 2.0, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Server: nginx/1.18.0
  Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2021 12:55:04 GMT
  ETag: "602d7410-83"
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 131
  Last-Modified: Wed, 17 Feb 2021 19:52:48 GMT
}` но этот сервер я сам настраивал.